# How to use capybara with watir / watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, watir, watir-webdriver

I just learned to use selenium with capaybara by setting

`Capybara.default_driver = :selenium`

But when I changed `default_driver` to `watir-webdriver` or `watir`, I am getting

`no driver called :Watir was found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the available drivers are only `:rack_test` and `:selenium` at the moment.

Comment: For reference, here's a link to the [capybara driver documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers)